# Skip import row, is not valid value "" for field "type"

Tags: magento, csv, data-import

I’m trying to upload a custom CSV file.

Does anyone know what this error means?

`Skip import row, is not valid value “” for field “type”`

Comment: This means, your CSV file is not in a perfect CSV format which has to be. Use a perfect Csv editor to edit the file

Comment: can you paste the sample content of your csv here in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better and easy way to import products please try the following way -

> - Add a product manually via **Admin**.
> - Export that product using **Import/Export** functionality of Magento.
> - Make your changes with the help of exported product data.
> - Add more product as per the Column of the CSV file.

Try to import and Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It helps, but I dont need the sku attribute in a attribute set. I removed the attribute but when I importing without sku it giving me error like :

`Skipping import row, required field "sku" is not defined.`

Comment: As per the error you have mentioned, without SKU you can import the products as the sku is the identity of the product.